# Concat VARCHAR2 fields in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle11g, concatenation, sql-view

For an SQL view I want to concat two fiels of varchar2-type

```
ROW  |  PNAME | FNAME
1    | JOHN   | DOE
2    | (null) | DOE
3    | JOHN   | (null)
4    | (null) | (null)
```

The result I want to get is

```
1  | 'JOHN DOE'
2  | 'DOE'
3  | 'JOHN'
4  | (null)
```

The best I could achieve so for looks like this

```
SELECT USER.PNAME || ' ' || USER.FNAME AS "NAME"
```

But this gives me the following result

```
1  | 'JOHN DOE'
2  | ' DOE'
3  | 'JOHN '
4  | ' '
```

I know why I get this result, but how could I get rid of the obsolete blank that I don't want to have in the result?

I am using Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT TRIM(USER.PNAME || ' ' || USER.FNAME) AS "NAME"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
SELECT DECODE(USER.PNAME,"",USER.PNAME,USER.PNAME || ' ') || USER.FNAME AS "NAME"
```

Comment: This doesn't work for ROW 3 - there's an extra space at the end.

Comment: Ty for your answer, but this gives me an `SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01741`